# Efficiently handling python processes

Tags: python, dictionary, python-multiprocessing

So for my project I have to get a list of genes and clean it from synonyms `ex. gene A might also be known as AA, so if in my original list there is AA and A I have to delete one of the two.`

The list of genes is provided by the user, and I read the synonyms from a text file.

Both are stored in `dictionaries`.

The list is `huuuuuge` (Trump joke) and I will have to call this function, many times in my pipeline. So my question is: Can I `multiprocess` this to make it faster?

My initial approach was as follows:

```
for g in genes:
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target = fixReoccurences, args =  (g, genes, synonyms, replaced, ))
    my_processes.append(process)
    process.start()

# Wait for *ALL* the processes to finish.
for p in my_processes:
    p.join()
```

But this approach quickly failed due to the fact that my script demanded 400 processes, that all of them are running a loop for ~40.000 iterations. It literally, froze my laptop.

So how can I tackle this issue by efficiently utilizing the multiple cores of my CPU to handle the processes?

Comment: Why do you have to call this function many times? Once you have cleaned up the inputs, doesn't it stay clean? Also, how large are the inputs? It seems like an efficient single process would probably be faster than multiprocessing, if all you are doing is a simple pass through a single file.

Comment: A dictionary with no values? Isn't that just a `set`?

Comment: @Austin Hastings because I have to analyze many inputs of various lengths.

Comment: So, most of your question is irrelevant. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @Peter Wood It's not a question of why I do things the way I do. My question is very specific and it's even stated in the description. `How can I multiprocess this without crashing my system due to the overwhelming workload? ` You may not like it, and it may be slower then doing it `1-threaded` but just for the sake of learning something new, I think it's worthwhile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`Pool.map`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map).

You can have a function which takes a gene and returns it or `None` if it should be filtered:

```
def filter_gene_if_synonym(gene, synonyms):
    return None if gene in synonymns else gene
```

You can bind an argument of a function using `partial`:

```
from functools import partial

filter_gene = partial(filter_gene_if_synonym,
                      synonyms=synonyms)
```

Then the function can be called just with a gene.

You can map a function to a sequence of data using a pool of processes:

```
pool = Pool(processes=4)
filtered_genes = [gene for gene in pool.map(filter_gene, genes)
                  if gene is not None]
```

The map function can also pass chunks of data to an appropriate function:

```
def filter_genes_of_synonyms(genes, synonyms):
    return [gene for gene in genes
            if gene not in synonymns]

filter_genes = partial(filter_genes, synonyms=synonyms)
```

and:

```
filtered_chunks = pool.map(filter_genes, genes, chunksize=50)
filtered_genes = [gene for chunk in filtered_chunks
                  for gene in chunk]
```

Answer (score 0):

I generated some random data, and then just did a straight-line replace:

```
#!python3

import random
import string

from mark_time import mark

synonyms = { 'AA': 'A', 'BB': 'B'}

population = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
population[-1] = 'AA'   # replace 'Z' with AA
population[-2] = 'BB'   # replace Y with BB

mark('Building inputs')
inputs = [random.choice(population) for _ in range(40000 * 400)]
mark('... done')

print(' '.join(inputs[:100]))

mark('Building outputs')
outputs = [synonyms.get(ch, ch) for ch in inputs]
mark('... done')

print(' '.join(outputs[:100]))
```

My output looks like this:

```
[1490996255.208] Building inputs
[1490996273.388] ... done
N A U W R W H D E BB V A S B B U W U V S W V E K N Q E R H R A H I V U X V E U G A R D M R S K F O R B B G R C U M C C Q T K G S S H W AA U BB K L W T L H V BB K H J D AA K P G W BB W C U G T P G M J L S J
[1490996273.388] Building outputs
[1490996276.12] ... done
N A U W R W H D E B V A S B B U W U V S W V E K N Q E R H R A H I V U X V E U G A R D M R S K F O R B B G R C U M C C Q T K G S S H W A U B K L W T L H V B K H J D A K P G W B W C U G T P G M J L S J
```

It's taking 18 seconds to build the input data, and only 3 seconds to replace synonyms. That's for 400 * 40,000 items. I'm not sure if your input items are individual genes or some sort of SAM sequences or what. More information in the question would probably be good. ;-)

I don't think you need to multiprocess this. Just do a good job processing the data as you read the file.

**Update**

Sorry for dropping out last night. But, beer.

Anyway, here's some code that will read in a synonyms file, with each line having a pair of words, like `"old new",` and build a dictionary that maps each old -> new word. It then "flattens" the dictionary, so that there is no need to repeat a lookup - each key is stored with its eventual value. I figure you can use this to read the synonym files, etc.

```
def get_synonyms(synfile):
    """Read in a list of 'synonym' pairs, two words per line A -> B.
    Store the pairs in a dict. "Flatten" the dict, so that if A->B and
    B->C, the dict stores A->C and B->C directly. Return the dict.
    """

    syns = {}

    # Read entries from the file
    with open(synfile) if type(synfile) is str else synfile as sf:
        for line in sf:
            if not line.strip(): continue
            k,v = line.strip().split()
            syns[k] = v

    # "flatten" the synonyms. If A -> B and B -> C, then change A -> C
    for k,v in syns.items():
        nv = v
        while nv in syns:
            nv = syns[nv]
        syns[k] = nv

    return syns

import io

synonyms = """
A B
B C
C D
E B
F A
AA G
""".strip()

#with open('synonyms.txt') as synfile:
with io.StringIO(synonyms) as synfile:
    thesaurus = get_synonyms(synfile)

assert sorted(thesaurus.keys()) == "A AA B C E F".split()
assert thesaurus['A'] == 'D'
assert thesaurus['B'] == 'D'
assert thesaurus['C'] == 'D'
assert thesaurus['E'] == 'D'
assert thesaurus['F'] == 'D'
assert thesaurus['AA'] == 'G'
```

Comment: because you are looking at the best-case scenario which is that `all the genes in the input list are true or duplicates`. But, what if there is one (or more) that are listed with an unofficial name? Namely, a gene that would be in one of the lists in the synonyms dictionary. And that could happen many times. So you have to traverse the synonyms dictionary and their lists in order to locate the queried term and replace it with the `key` to the list.

Comment: Absolutely not! That is the kind of thing you do *before* you start processing. If A -> B -> C, then your dictionary should say { A->C, B->C} right at the start. As you say, you could have to do this hundreds or thousands of times during processing, so why not just do it once at the start.

Comment: But you can't know that information beforehand! It's just the nature of the data! you can't know without comparing with the provided genelist! And as I said, I have to do this for multiple (different) lists!

Comment: Yes, you can. The synonyms are known before you start processing the large datasets, even if they come from a file. So you insert a step to 'flatten' the synonyms first.